# How to display a continuous diagonal line with an SVG externalgraphic in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, svg

I need to symbolize a polygon layer with geoserver using an SVG file as an external graphic. The polygon should be filled with diagonal line. I have created the SVG in Inkscape using a 400px x 400px SVG Graphic. Geoserver renders the polyons as expected, but the SVG pattern has a gap between them. How can I remove this unsightly gap? This Problem does not occur when served with DEEGREE, so I am assuming it is a geoserver bug.

[Link to Layer Hier](https://egov3.heidekreis.de/geoserver/ALKIS/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=ALKIS:AXLANDWIRTSCHAFT&styles=&bbox=551817,5864372,553267,5866312&width=1200&height=800&srs=EPSG:25832&format=application/openlayers)

[image]

Here is the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>


<svg width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">;



<polygon points="0 0  50 0 0 50" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="1px" 
fill="#FF0000" />

<polygon points="150 0 250 0 0 250 0 150" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-
width="1px" fill="#FF0000" />

<polygon points="0 400 0 350 350 0 400 0 400 50 50 400" stroke="#FF0000" 
stroke-width="1px" fill="#FF0000" />

<polygon points="400 150 400 250 250 400 150 400" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-
width="1px" fill="#FF0000" />

<polygon points="400 350 400 400 350 400" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-
width="1px" fill="#FF0000" />





</svg>
```

Here is the SLD Symbolizer.

```
                <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                <sld:Fill>
                    <sld:GraphicFill>
                        <sld:Graphic>
                            <sld:ExternalGraphic>
                                <sld:OnlineResource
                                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"; xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ROK_gewerbe.svg"/>
                                    <sld:Format>image/svg</sld:Format>
                                </sld:ExternalGraphic>
                                <sld:Size>20</sld:Size>
                                <sld:Rotation>0</sld:Rotation>
                            </sld:Graphic>
                        </sld:GraphicFill>
                    </sld:Fill>
                    <sld:Stroke>
                        <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#666666</sld:CssParameter>
                        <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</sld:CssParameter>
                        <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Stroke>
                </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

Comment: Please share the SVG. Also, I assume the question is "generic", there are better ways to create a hatch fill in GeoServer.

Comment: Above is the SVG. Using <WellKnownName>shape://backslash</WellKnownName> I am able to get a continuous line, but unfortunately due to the way the client works, it is required that the symbology uses SVGs.

Comment: You said it's 10px, but the ordinates in the SVG and its translation suggest otherwise. Maybe just try to remove the transforms, they are at least weird.

Comment: I have updated the SVG and the question to contain the newest svg file. Is anyone able to reproduce this error?

Comment: I assume is it a geoserver bug because DEEGREE renders this as a continuous line.

Comment: If this is happening on a supported GeoServer version (2.12.x or newer) you should report it at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to append the following vendor option which removes any margins between SVGs

```
<se:VendorOption name="graphic-margin">-1</se:VendorOption>
```

[image]

Here the link to a working demo.

[LINK](https://egov3.heidekreis.de/geoserver/ALKIS/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=ALKIS:AXLANDWIRTSCHAFT3&styles=&bbox=551817,5864372,553267,5866312&width=1200&height=800&srs=EPSG:25832&format=application/openlayers)